# Boolean is not working with if statement

Tags: php

I have a code on which Boolean values are coming dynamically on a variable ($bool) but with the 'if statement' it is not working properly.I have tried both 0/1 and true/false with the $bool.

If i write following code then it prints featured for all:

```
<?php if($bool == 0) : ?> <div>Featured</div> <?php endif; ?>
```

and If i write following code then it prints nothing

```
<?php if($bool == 1) : ?> <div>Featured</div> <?php endif; ?>
```

But i have both true and false values.Please help!!!

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($bool);` ?

Comment: If `$bool` is boolean, you could do `if($bool) :`

Comment: output of var_dump($bool) for some div it is 0 and for some div its is 1 with string,that what i exactly need,but with the if statement it is not working.

Comment: can you paste all the output that you get from var_dump?

Comment: Here is the output by var_dump:
string(34) "1"

Comment: @Johny ^^ See the **(34)** <- ?! Try to use: `trim($bool)`; Does that do the trick for you?

Answer (score 1):

You are a victim of the type juggling.

`$bool` is a string, and in php `var_dump('string' == 0)` is always `true`. Look [this table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) from the documentation. If you use `==` instead of the strict comparison operator `===` and you compare the string with an integer, then the string is always translate to a number. In this specific case

```
var_dump((int) 'string'); // 0
```

Comment: I have converted the string to integer by int,intval,bool function but nothing is working.Here is the output by var_dump: 
string(34) "1"

Comment: You have a string with 34 byte. You can't convert it like that. What's really inside $bool?

Comment: only boolean values 0 and 1

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
//To check the what value is return use vardump
var_dump($bool); //comment after the check the value.

if($bool == true){
    //echo your value for true statement
}else if($bool == false){
    //echo your value for false statement
}
?>
```

Comment: i have used var_dump,it gives output for the true statement like string(34) " 0 " and for the false statement it gives string(34) " 1 "

Comment: boolean staement 0=="true" and 1 = "false". so what is the issue on echo the values.